# String Switch Implementation alternatives in OOP

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, enums, switch-statement

I have two objects say Object a and Object b. Both of these objects have some properties say name, age etc. I want to write a method where I pass some string value as a parameter to this method and it prints some value for both the objects. Which value to print is decided by the String that is being passed to the method. To be more clear:-

```
Class A{
String name;
String age;
//getters and setters for name and age
}

Class B{ 
String salary;
String level;
//getters and setters for name and age
}




public String getValue(String attribute)
{
    switch(attribute)
    {
        case "name":
        System.out.println(a.getName());
        System.out.println(b.getSalary());
        break;
        case "age":
        System.out.println(a.getAge());
        System.out.println(b.getLevel());
        break;
    }
}
```

Now using switch statements does the job. But I have read that switch statements are not a good practice for OO design. What are the other ways I can do this? I have read something about using enums but I am not very clear about it.

Comment: I don't see why switches wouldn't be good practice, OOP or no.

Comment: Unrelated to your question but are classes A and B identical? Because that wouldn't be very good OO Design.

Comment: I have read several discussions about this, so I am just curious to know what other alternatives are available. Here is one of those discussions:-
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/550919/does-anyone-disagree-with-the-statement-using-switch-is-bad-oop-style

Comment: @Drew: That is actually a good point. I have many other properties for each class in actual implementation but I didnt want to list them all here. Anywayss I will edit the question a little.

Answer (score 5):

The "right" answer is probably inheritance. I'll include a couple other options here, just for completeness.

## Inheritance Example

This is probably the "right" answer.

**PROS**

- Compile-time checking
- Most "OO" solution

**CONS**

- Implementations must be coupled to a specific interface

---

```
public interface X {
    public Object getField1();
    public Object getField2();
}

public class A implements X {
    /* implementation... */
}

public class A implements X {
    /* implementation... */
}

X x=create();
System.out.println(x.getField1());
System.out.println(x.getField2());
```

## Reflection Example

**PROS**

- Simple
- No inheritance relationship required
- Somewhat beholden to objects to (a) behave like Java beans with proper accessor names; (b) have public fields; or (c) have a security policy that allows calls to [`setAccessible()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html#setAccessible%28java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject[],%20boolean%29)

**CONS**

- No compile-time checking

---

```
// Note that we're accessing fields directly. You should probably use accessor methods instead.
Object x=create();
for(String name : new String[]{"all", "your", "fields"}) {
    Field field=x.getClass().getField(name);
    Object value=field.get(x);
    System.out.println(name+" = "+value);
}
```

## Enum Example

**PROS**

- Compile time checking
- Easy to add fields or objects over time
- No inheritance relationship required
- It's easy to treat a field as a parameter

**CONS**

- Repetitive
- Verbose

---

```
enum Value {
    FIELD1 {
        public Object get(A a) {
            return a.field1;
        }

        public Object get(B b) {
            return b.field1;
        }
    }, ...;

    public abstract Object get(A a);

    public abstract Object get(B b);

};

A a=create();
B b=create();
for(Value value : Value.values()) {
    System.out.println(value.get(a));
    System.out.println(value.get(b));
}
```

Comment: Nice Explaination! Thanks!